# Multiplication and Division Bug

Tags: unity, c#

Hi guys first time poster with a quick question. I'm just getting started with coding and as an easy exercise I wanted to make a block move and sprint. I got it to do that but when I press the shift key too fast the getKeyUp part divides the speed variable too many times. How do I fix this?

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float speedmutiplier = 2f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("left shift"))
        {
            speed = speed * speedmutiplier;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp("left shift"))
        {
            speed = speed / speedmutiplier;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *too many times*. Could you maybe record what happens and upload a video or gif showing it here?

Comment: It is, in fact, impossible to tell you what is going wrong when you do not tell us what it is doing to begin with.

Comment: I don't think you actually want that `GetKeyUp` section, if I understand correctly? There is no reason I can possibly see for you to be dividing the speed by the same value that you use to boost it on `KeyDown`. Now, _friction_... that there is another story altogether.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you're trying to implement a simple running state. The problem is that you're using `GetKeyDown` and `GetKeyUp`. Those functions will return true in their respective frames, but if you press the button in really quick succession, you might be able to press the button down, then up and then down again in the same frame, but the next up action will be in the next frame, therefore calling the `GetKeyUp` function twice but not the `GetKeyDown` function.

What you should be doing instead is, checking whether the shift key is pressed at the start of the `FixedUpdate` and then applying the multiplier there, using a base speed and a variable speed.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float baseSpeed = 5f;
    public float speedmutiplier = 2f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float speed = baseSpeed;
        if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            speed = baseSpeed * speedmutiplier;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, -speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'd like to have a maximum and a minimum speed, you can [Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) the `speed` between a maximum and a minimum.

Like this:

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float speedmutiplier = 2f;
    public float minimumSpeed = 1.25f;
    public float maximumSpeed = 640f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // ...
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("left shift"))
        {
            speed = speed * speedmutiplier;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp("left shift"))
        {
            speed = speed / speedmutiplier;
        }

        speed = Mathf.Clamp(speed, minimumSpeed, maximumSpeed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the use of FixedUpdate() together with GetKeyUp/GetKeyDown. Unity resets them **once per Update** loop. When they are used in FixedUpdate() Unity can "miss" some of them.

As a rule use FixedUpdate mainly for physics related stuff, the rest goes to Update (or rarely LateUpdate).

So you should replace FixedUpdate with Update. Additionally I would still replace GetKeyDown/GetKeyUp with GetKey (look @John Hamilton answer on how you can do that).

Here is some additional info from Unity docs that may help you understand how Update and FixedUpdate work and why FixedUpdates is intended for physics related things:

> Unlike the main frame update, Unity’s physics system does work to a fixed timestep, which is important for the accuracy and consistency of the simulation. At the start of the physics update, Unity sets an “alarm” by adding the fixed timestep value onto the time when the last physics update ended. The physics system will then perform calculations until the alarm goes off.

Translation for the other mere mortals like me:

When the time between each Update is small (i.e. high frame rate) then Unity runs one(or even zero) FixedUpdate then one Update and repeat the whole process. But when the time between Updates becomes too long (i.e low frame rate) then Unity begins to "insert" more FixedUpdates in-between Updates because it tries to maintain fixed time between FixedUpdates.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `deltaTime` is properly used in the speed computation. Unless you are comfortable with approximations, a correct, framerate-independent implementation should probably use `Pow()`:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("left shift"))
    {
        speed = speed * Math.Pow(speedmutiplier, Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp("left shift"))
    {
        speed = speed / Math.Pow(speedmutiplier, Time.deltaTime);
    }
```